# How to merge data from google sheet into google slide (all data into one google slide rather than multipl slide)

Tags: google-slides-api

I am new to google script. I have a project to merge data from the google sheet into google slide. I need to create a slide where all data is merge into a single file slide. I have google many solution but it seems not working. 
Even though I have 10 data, but only the first data is merge into first slide only. 
Please help

Here are my codes:

```
function slidemerge()
{
// Use the Sheets API to load data, one record per row.
var srcSlideId = 'id';
var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid').getDataRange().getValues();
var copysrcSlideIndex = 1; // 0 means page 1.
var copydstSlideIndex = 2; // 0 means page 1.

  // Duplicate the template presentation using the Drive API.
  var copyTitle = 'Report'+ Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "dd-MMM-yyyy");

  var copyFile = {
    title: copyTitle,
    parents: [{id: 'root'}]
  };

  copyFile = Drive.Files.copy(copyFile, srcSlideId);
  var presentationCopyId = copyFile.id;
  var src = SlidesApp.openById(presentationCopyId).getSlides() 
            [copysrcSlideIndex];
// For each record, create a new merged presentation.
for (var i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {
  var row = values[i];
  var pid=row[9];
  var customerName = row[10];
  var slip=row[11];

  var dupslideid=SlidesApp.openById(presentationCopyId).insertSlide(copydstSlideIndex, src);

  // Create the text merge (replaceAllText) requests for this presentation.
  requests = [{
    replaceAllText: {
      pageObjectIds: src[dupslideid.getObjectId()],
      containsText: {
        text: '{{ID}}',
        matchCase: true
      },
      replaceText: pid,
    }
  },{
    replaceAllText: {
      containsText: {
        text: '{{Name}}',
        matchCase: true
      },
      replaceText: customerName
    }
  },{
  replaceAllShapesWithImage: {
    imageUrl: slip,
    replaceMethod: 'CENTER_INSIDE',
    containsText: {
      text: '{{Slip}}',
      matchCase: true
    }
  }
}];

  // Execute the requests for this presentation.
  var result = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({
    requests: requests
  }, presentationCopyId);  
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in the documentation on [Merging Data into Slides](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/merge)?

Comment: Yes. i did. that documentation is to merge data into multiple slides files. i want to merge the data into single slide only but multiple page.